# List of Algorithms header format

Tags: table-of-contents, algorithms, algorithm2e

Does anyone know why the header of List of Algorithms is not equal to the format of List of Tables when both using with

```
\listoftables
```

or

```
\listofalgorithms
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Ok seems to be a problem with the LLNCS template. They did change the List of Tables and List of Figures header format, but they did not consider the List of Algorithms.

Comment: @user23947: This question has been closed as too localized. In order to re-open it, consider adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) so that community members can easily see your setup and provide the most accurate solution.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm2e package doesn't play nice with this.
I had to hack it (using memoir, might make a difference, as it redefines lots of stuff!):

Example:

```
\newlistof{listofalgorithms}{loa}{\listalgorithmcfname}
```